# GMaven plugin execute a script in parent directory

Tags: maven, groovy, gmaven-plugin

I have parent/child maven project structure. I am trying to run a Groovy script from a parent project like shown below

```
<source>${project.parent.basedir}/project-common/src/main/scripts/myscript.groovy</source>
```

But it wouldn't recognize this path and I get an error groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: script1385579701154.$() is applicable for argument types: (script1385579701154$_run_closure1) values:

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: From what I can remember `${project.parent.basedir}` works in Maven 2 but doesn't work in Maven 3. You could give `${project.basedir}/../project-common/src/main/scripts/myscript.groovy` a try instead.

Comment: glad to hear it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`${project.parent.basedir}` works in Maven 2 but doesn't work in Maven 3.

You can however use a relative path to get to your parent project. i.e.

```
${project.basedir}/../project-common/src/main/scripts/myscript.groovy
```